# Replace all inside bitset with a differently sized bitset

Tags: java, algorithm, binary

I'm currently dealing with a binary file that will later on be written into a different binary file. This is very important and is the reason I'm hesitant to use ArrayLists and other lists, as they tend to not play nicely with me trying to write it into a file directly.

I've retrieved the bytes out of this binary and separated them into bits using BitSet. I think I've figured out how to find the bitset I want to replace. Currently this looks kinda like this:

```
try {
                InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filepath);
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("output.bin");
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(4096 * 8);
                BitSet bitString = new BitSet(search.length());
                BitSet bitReplace = new BitSet(replace.length());
                // Search String to bitset
                for (int i = search.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (search.charAt(i) == '1') {
                        bitString.set(search.length() - i - 1);
                    }
                }
                // Replace String to bitset
                for (int i = replace.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (replace.charAt(i) == '1') {
                        bitReplace.set(replace.length() - i - 1);
                        }
                }
                while (inputStream.read(buffer) != -1) {
                    bitSet = BitSet.valueOf(buffer);
                    bufferCount++;
                    // GET 4096 BYTES AT THE SAME TIME
                    // TURN THEM INTO BITS, WE END UP WITH 4096*8 bits
                    // COMPARE EVERY SEARCHSIZE BITS
                    for (int i = 0; i < bitSet.length(); i++) { 
                        if (bitSet.get(i, i + bitString.length()).equals(bitString)) {
                            //TODO: Replace bitset with a different bit set
                        }
                    }
                }
                inputStream.close();
                outputStream.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("IOException");
                System.exit(1);
            }
```

What I'm missing is how to set an existing bitsets once the pattern of bits have been found with a different bitset(could be differently sized).

So to illustrate:

> Find: 01010 replace with: 001111

Would turn this sequence of bits:

> 00|01010|01000000000000010

into:

> 00|001111|010000000000000010

Abstractly I've thought of a solution, to be like this:

```
1. Find the pattern that matches the SEARCHed pattern
2. Replace a bitset with a completely different bitset(this is what I'm struggling with, I was thinking about just appending everything to the end of the file, but that would not be very efficient in terms of read/write 
3. Shift the other bits to the left or to the right based on the difference between the sizes of the searched pattern and the pattern we're replacing with.
4. Write into file.
```

Comment: I hope performance isn't a big deal, since this approach won't work well with big data or where high speed is needed.

Comment: It's not as big of a deal as actually working is :P

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function `setBitsFromIndex(int i, BitSet source, BitSet dest)`:

```
private static void setBitsFromIndex(int i, BitSet source, BitSet dest) {
    for (int j = 0; j < source.length(); j++) {
        dest.set(i+j, source.get(j));
    }
}
```

Then, in your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bitSet.length() - bitString.length(); i++) { 
    if (bitSet.get(i, i + bitString.length()).equals(bitString)) {

        //Replace bitset with a different bit set

        BitSet tempBitSet = bitSet.get(i + bitString.length(), bitSet.length());
        setBitsFromIndex(i, bitReplace, bitSet);
        setBitsFromIndex(i + bitReplace.length(), tempBitSet, bitSet);

        // if bitReplace is shorter than bitString, we may need to clear trailing bits
        if (bitReplace.length() < bitString.length()) {
            bitSet.clear(i + bitReplace.length() + tempBitSet.length(), bitSet.length());
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

**BE WARNED:** The length of a BitSet is NOT it's capacity, or even the length it was prior to the last time you set a bit. It is the index + 1 of the **HIGHEST SET (1) BIT**, so your `bitReplace`, `bitString`, and `bitSet` BitSets might not be the length you think they are if they have 0s in the most-significant bits. If you want to include leading zeros, you have to track the desired size of your `bitReplace` and `bitString` BitSets independently.

Comment: I think I'm abandoning BitSet altogether. I've just realized the smallest size is 64. Which kind of defeats the whole point of getting per-bit granularity.

Comment: It's just the capacity. A BitSet is internally an array of longs. So one long is the smallest sized array you can have (and still store something). If you do `BitSet bs = new BitSet()` and then `bs.set(2)`, `bs.length()` will be 3, not 64.